# Receiving "Message board service started" randomly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Randomly on my Android Galaxy S2, I'm receiving a message nag **"Message board service started"**.

It can happens in an application, in the app drawer or anywhere randomly.

I'm unable to find any sources talking about this message.

Do you have an idea?

Android 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ....

- Message Board service started
- BlueLocate service started

Here is the app causing theses messages : Connectdroid

[image: ConnectDroid Settings]